# Communicate nodeJs with symfony rabbitMq

Tags: node.js, docker, rabbitmq, symfony

Node Js : I created a consumer with nodejs and socket for communicating with 
rabbitMq and symfony

### file : consumer.js

```
var http = require('http'),
url = require('url'),
amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');


amqp.connect('amqp://user:pass@192.168.99.10:55672', function(err, conn) {
conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
var q = 'hello';

ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q);
ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
  console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
  }, {noAck: true});
 });
});
```

### File : App.js

```
 var server = require('http').createServer();
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(client){
console.log('here');
client.on('event', function(data){});
client.on('disconnect', function(){});
 });
server.listen(3000);
```

**Symfony 3**

I created a Producer with symfony 3

```
 ProducerController

 class ProducerController extends Controller
 {

 /**
 * @Route("/producer", name="producer")
 */
  public function uploadAction(Request $request)
  {

   $userId =  mt_rand(1, 1000000);

 $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject('Sujet de l\'email')
->setFrom('test@xxx.com')
->setTo('destinaire@xxx.com')
->setBody($this->renderView('index.html.twig', ['userId' =>$userId]), 'text/html');
    $this->get('old_sound_rabbit_mq.message_producer')->publish(serialize($message));     

 return $this->render('welcome.html.twig', ['userId' => $userId]);

}

}
```

config.yml

```
  old_sound_rabbit_mq:
 connections:
   default:
   host:     '192.168.99.10' # hostname and port of the rabbitmq server
   port:     55672
   user:     'user'
   password: 'pass'
   vhost:    '/'
   lazy:     true # a lazy connection avoids unnecessary connections to the broker on every request

producers:
 message:
   connection:       default # connects to the default connection configured above
   exchange_options: {name: 'message', type: direct}
```

the problem now that I don't know how I can communicate with the producer and consumer.
node consumer.js execute normal and wait a message
node app.js  It shows me nothing

Comment: Based on the tags, you're using docker. Post any docker commands you used.

Comment: just docker-compose up
rabbitMq works with docker and symfony

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not be publishing to the same queue.

I would use the [docs, exactly as they are](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) for both PHP and Javascript for sending and receiving before experimenting further.